# How to get the local name and MAC address of the BLE adapter?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know I can get the name and MAC address of the Classic Bluetooth Adapter like so:

```
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    String name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
    String address = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```

but how do I get the name and address of the BLE adapter? Or is it the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same. However Android usually uses a random resolvable address instead of its public one, and you can't extract that one. It changes every 15 minutes anyway.